# Why does this WCF call fail when passing in a federated security token

Tags: wcf, wcf-security, wif, federated-identity

I'm trying to pass a security token from a client application into a WCF service for authentication.

For this example I'm just using the standard File, New WCF Application project and trying to call the GetData method.

I get the following exception on the client

> {"The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the
>   action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData' is incorrect or because
>   the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
>   because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context
>   token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to
>   inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding."}

If I enable tracing on the WCF service I can see the following error

> There was no channel that could accept the message with action
>   'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData'.

The Web.Config for my service looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />        
  </configSections>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <!--Configure STS-->
  <system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://stsserver.security.int/myApp" />
      </audienceUris>
      <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089">
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="‎3c8fc34bd483b07ba0d1509827fc4788c36247e4" name="StartSSL Login" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"/>
    </identityConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        <binding name ="IdentityServer">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Services.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="CertificateBehavior">
        <endpoint name="ws" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="IdentityServer" contract="Services.IService1" address=""/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CertificateBehavior">
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>    
</configuration>
```

The method in my client application that calls this WCF service looks like this

```
static void CallSecuredService(SecurityToken samlToken)
{
    var binding = new WS2007FederationHttpBinding((WSFederationHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential));
    binding.Security.Message.IssuedKeyType = SecurityKeyType.BearerKey;
    binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;

    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/myservice/Service1.svc"));
    factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    factory.Credentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true;
    var proxy = factory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(samlToken);

    Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetData(1));
}
```

Any pointers as to things I should check would be great as I'm at a bit of a loss with this one now. I'm not sure how I can debug this any further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally managed to get past this error. The problem was a small miss match between the service and client bindings.

Changing my bindings in the web.config to this fixed the issue

```
<bindings>
  <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
    <binding name ="IdentityServer">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message issuedKeyType="BearerKey" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```